# How to isolate the runtime of a dynamic loaded library (dlopen)

Tags: dlopen, dlsym

Take for instance an application that needs to load several other shared libraries. Each with the same interface. How can I prevent that a crash in any of the loaded shared libraries to not crash the main application? Keep in mind that they are only loaded one at a time.

Essentially making so that a crash in a call of a symbol from `dlsym` would not crash the main application.

One of the solutions, like the one bellow, would be to just `fork()` the main program, load and call the library in the child.

lib.so:

```c
int foo() {
    int a = ((int*)0)[1]; // die

    return a;
};
```

main.c:

```c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fork() error");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        void* handle = dlopen("./lib.so", RTLD_NOW);

        if (!handle) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        }

        dlerror();

        int (*foo)(void) = dlsym(handle, "foo");

        char* error = dlerror();
        if (error != NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
            exit(1);
        }

        foo(); // only the child will die

        exit(0);
    } else {
        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        printf("child status %d\n", status);
    }

    puts("exit parent");

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Since `fork` without `exec` can
lead to other problems.

Comment: For the same reason, Oracle RDBMS supports plugins, but runs them as separate processes so that the plugin couldn't corrupt the main process.

Comment: Yes, just questioning if there is a better way of doing this. What I came up with is fork/exec into the same binary (with a different name) and do the loading this way, as to not waste to much memory. Probably better to have different binaries, but, I'm limited to only one.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way of doing this?

No.